# Add sudo permission to a group of users for specific shell file

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I have been looking for an answer for a while now, but I cannot find it.

I have a shell script located at: /home/myuser/shell.sh, which requires sudo to be run. I want all my users from `mygroup` to be able to run it without password.

So I executed: `visudo`, and added this line at the end of the file:

```
%mygroup ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/myuser/shell.sh
```

The problem is that it is not working. When I try to execute `sh /home/myuser/shell.sh` as one of the users of `mygroup`, it asks me for the sudo password.

Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try without the space after the colon ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I just tried but it still doesn't work

Comment: OK, I found one way which is to allow all the commands inside the shell script to `mygroup` inside the sudoers file. However, isn't there any way to make it possible for the whole script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Run it with sudo

*visudo* affects *sudo* behaviour, so you have to use it.

But don't use `sh /.../shell.sh`, make the script executable first

```
chmod +x /home/myuser/shell.sh
```

then you'll be able to do

```
sudo /home/myuser/shell.sh
```

without the password. Then remove all *sudo* calls in the script.

Comment: the file is executable with root access, and the sudo is used inside the file, that means basically that there is a command like `sudo xxx` inside shell.sh

Comment: @EmmanuelO Then you have two options. Either remove all those sudo calls or create a visudo entry for this `xxx` command.

Comment: Thank you very much! :-)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the users are in the group to allow sudo.